# VS Code UI language is not propagated to python extension command palette

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have added the official microsoft python extension (v2019.2.5558) to my VS Code installation (v1.32.1). VS Code runs with the default UI language *en*, which is set in *locale.json*. I have never installed any additional language packs.

Since the UI language of VS Code is set to *en*, I would expect that this setting is propagated to the command palette. However, this does not seem to be the case as you can see here:

[image]

Some commands appear in english (as one would expect), but others appear in german (which is the language of my windows OS).

At this point, i am not entirely sure if this is a bug or a feature. Am I missing any additional *extension-level* language setting one has to set to make the language uniformly english? Or should this be handled by *locale.json* and is therefore a bug?

I am using other official MS extensions (like C\C++, C#, Java) which display all commands uniformly in english, which would hint at a bug in the python extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is indeed a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62623#issuecomment-467347288) yet the problem is not from the Python extension. As pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62623#issuecomment-463832571) from a relevant GitHub issue, the default locale language is not considered when there have been no changes to the file.

The main fix for this would be to change your language in `locale.json` to something else (e.g. `de` for German), save the file, restart the editor and repeat these steps but setting back `en` as the locale. Otherwise you could just comment the line and put it back afterwards.

For temporarily setting the language of the editor, you could also use the `--locale` parameter when opening VS Code as explained in [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales#_setting-the-language).